# Try to find a better way to layout 4 images

Tags: html, css, layout

I have 4 images and try to layout them as my expections. I know there is a very easy way to layout with table layout like the following snippet.

```html
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td/>
<td><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
<td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
<td><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
<td><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

But I don't want to do it with table layout for HTML Semantic reason. So How do I do it with CSS ?

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for you tip. I have did some basic research. I post my question here ,  because I believe it's a quiet basic and important question and I expect a better or the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, one possible approach is using an unordered list of images with `Flexbox` position

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 175px;
}

li { 
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 100%; }

li:not(:first-child) { flex-basis: 33.3%; }

img { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Since you say there are several ways to do it, could you please show more possible solutions?  The reason why I ask questions here is not only to solve my issue, but also to find more possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Check this. Hope it helps.

```css
ul{text-align:center; width:200px;}
ul li{display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; width:50px}
ul li:first-child{clear:both;display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
ul li img{width:100%}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.pimg.jp/015/085/802/1/15085802.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```